# how to Use Blockchain receive api without exchange rate?

Tags: php, laravel, blockchain

i have integrated blockchain recieve api for blockchain payment gateway. but when i go to pay enter amount to add balance it converts that amount into usd

i want to receive directly in BTC not in usd . when i remove below URL from my coding it gives error please help

```
 if ($sendto!="") {
                $api = "https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=".$data['amount'];

                $usd = file_get_contents($api );
                $tran->btc_amo = $usd;
                $tran->btc_acc = $sendto;
                $tran->save();
```

Comment: anyone here to help?

Comment: You are not using `receive api` you are using `Exchange Rates API` which needs `currency` and `value` https://blockchain.info/api/exchange_rates_api

Answer (score 0):

I read their [documentation](https://blockchain.info/api/exchange_rates_api) and they don't have USD to BTC. But, if you need USD to BTC. You can try it yourself like the following

```
$one_usd_in_btc = https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=1
$usd_to_btc     = $one_usd_in_btc * your_usd
```

Comment: they have usd to btc. please check this if ($sendto!="") {
                $api = "https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=".$data['amount'];
               

               $usd = file_get_contents($api);
                $tran->btc_amo = $usd;
                $tran->btc_acc = $sendto;
                $tran->save();

Answer (score 0):

If you want the inverse:

NOT USD to BTC from the API

BUT BTC to USD then you need the inverse.

Original formula

```
const bitcoinrate;

function usd_to_btc($usd) {
    $btc = $usd * bitcoinrate;
}
```

The opposite

```
function btc_to_usd($btc) {
    $usd = $btc / bitcoinrate;
}
```

But your code already contains the amount in USD in the first place. `$data['amount']`

Comment: i only want that user see same amount that he has entererd. mean if he enter 5 it should be five 5 bitcoin  not bitcoin of 5 usd.